# how to create treeview for xml data file in c#.net

Tags: c#, treeview

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Synergy>
    <INDATE>17/08/2014 Friday</INDATE>
    <INTIME>-</INTIME>
    <OUTTIME>-</OUTTIME>
    <OUTDATE>17/08/2014</OUTDATE>
    <LUNCH>-</LUNCH>
    <EFFORTS>-</EFFORTS>
    <OPERATIONS>Weekoff</OPERATIONS>
    <COMMENTS>lkjhkl</COMMENTS>
  </Synergy>
</NewDataSet>
```

This is my xml data file...and these are filds.i try to create a treeview for this file..i want to code for expand to synergy to display the indate,outdate......,comments.using c# language...

Answer (score 0):

C# .NET offers a really easy framewok for XML (`System.Xml`)

You could load your XML-Document into an XDocument Object like this:

```
public XDocument LoadXMLfromFile(string DataFilePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(DataFilePath)) {
            var xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            return xDoc;
    }
}
```

then you could iterate through the nodes and pass them to your TreeView

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlNodeList senergy = doc.SelectNodes("NewDataSet/Synergy");

        foreach (XmlNode node in senergy)
        {
            TreeNode senergyNode = new TreeNode("senergy");
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("INDATE").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("INTIME").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("OUTTIME").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("OUTDATE").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("LUNCH").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("EFFORTS").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("OPERATIONS").InnerText);
            senergyNode.Nodes.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("COMMENTS").InnerText);

            tvSenergy.Nodes.Add(senergyNode);
        }
```

Also donot forget about using System.XMl.